# JavaFX tab through editable cells

Tags: javafx, listener, tableview

I have defined my own editable cell for a TableView. Everything works great but I want to be able to tab through the cells. Say I'm in cell [2,2] on a tab press I want the selected cell to go to [3,2]. Is this possible? How should I go about achieving this? Should I add a listener to the TableCell or the TableColumn?

Here is my custom TableCell

```
class EditingCell extends TableCell<Student, String> {

   private TextField textField;

   public EditingCell(Assignment assign) {
       this.setTooltip(new Tooltip(assign.getMaxPoints() + " pts max"));
   }

   @Override
   public void startEdit() {
       if (!isEmpty()) {
           super.startEdit();
           createTextField();
           setText(null);
           setGraphic(textField);
           textField.selectAll();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void cancelEdit() {
       super.cancelEdit();

       setText((String) getItem());
       setGraphic(null);
   }

   @Override
   public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
       super.updateItem(item, empty);

       if (empty) {
           setText(null);
           setGraphic(null);
       } else {
           if (isEditing()) {
               if (textField != null) {
                   textField.setText(getString());
               }
               setText(null);
               setGraphic(textField);
           } else {
               setText(getString());
               setGraphic(null);
           }
       }
   }

   private void createTextField() {
       textField = new TextField(getString());
       textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
       textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
           @Override
           public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
               Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                if (!arg2) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a KeyListener to your `textField`. Try adding the following code to your `createTextField()`

```
textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
       if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
           commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
       } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
           cancelEdit();
       } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
           commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
           TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(!t.isShiftDown());
           if (nextColumn != null) {
               getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(), nextColumn);
           }
       }
   }
});
```

There are a few more things that you will have to take care of. For a complete example, please follow

https://gist.github.com/abhinayagarwal/9383881

Comment: Cool solution, the edit(row index, col) doesn't seem to do as advertised though. When I tab, the edit is commited but the call to edit() does not set the next cell in editing mode

Comment: @JamesFazio The code has a small misplacement of `}`. Can you try now ?

Comment: Hey @ItachiUchiha it wasn't a compile problem, it just doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yeah, I tried that also, when I press tab it just enters the data and then highlights the row, do you have this working?

Comment: Hmm, what seems to be happening is it tries to enter edit mode for the next cell, but it is prevented because the previously edited cell is still selected. But I figured out a solution that seems to work for me, instead of calling edit(), I use getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();

Comment: Your example works great for String columns - do you have one that will allow the use of a converter (i.e. forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter())  Thanks.

Comment: for me the solution is working like a charm
i would like to suggest a little improvement:
getTableView().scrollToColumn(nextColumn);
after the getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(), nextColumn); line
this way it will scroll to editable column cell even if it no visible i.e. if the table has lots of columns